# In my demo React code when click the button, it do not response

Tags: reactjs

Why click the button, it do not response?

my demo code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-knuth-kwf55c

I check my code, do not find the issue, please help with this.

Comment: Change the `top` property from `24` to `24px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that,
as All elements are set using `position:absolute` content div is overlapping with header.

Which results in hiding header for interaction. So when we are clicking click is actually being fired on content, not button (See below).

[image]

There are couple things we can do,

- either remove position absolute from DIV
- Changing top position of content
- Calculate height of content so it doesn't overlap with footer using CSS [view-port units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) / [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function

Answer (score 0):

try to comment out `id="content"` div and `id="footer"` div.

**because they are over-laping on the button that's why button is not clickable.**

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work